# How to check if an id value exists in an object array

Tags: javascript

Given an array "posts" of objects {id: "x", title: "title"}, i need **to verify whether there is a previously entered id before entering a new post** (via form in which id is a field).

I tried looping through posts, but it causes problems on entering repeated new data. Thank you for your help, this is driving me mad.

```
// ADD NEW POST FROM FORM TO ARRAY
$("#form").submit(function(event) {
    event.preventDefault();
    var id = Number($("#idPost").val());
    var title = $("#titlePost").val();
    var date = new Date($("#data").val());
// CHECK IF id ALREADY EXISTS, IF YES, BLOCK ENTRY    
    for(num of posts){
        console.log (id, num.id);
        if(id === num.id){ 
            console.log("error");
        } else {
            var post = new Post(id, title, date);
        }                
    };      
});
```

Comment: [`Array.prototype.some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some)

Answer (score 1):

As @Andreas suggested, you can use [`Array.Some()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/some) to find element exist in array or not.

```
 var found = posts.some(el => el.id  === id ); // It returns true if id exist in an array
 if(found)
 {
  //Your codes here
 }
```

Or you can try with [`Array.Filter()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/filter) to find element is exist or not in array.

```
var found = posts.filter(el => el.id === id).length > 0; // .length returns 1 if id exist in an array
if(found)
{
   //Your code goes here
}
```

You can try [`Array.find()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) or [`Array.IndexOf()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/indexOf) to perform same operation

Following implementation with `Array.Some()`

```js
//Lets consider below is the value in posts arry

var posts = [ { id: 1, username: 'foo' },{ id: 2, username: 'bar' } ];

var newObj = {"id": 3, "username": 'prasad'};
//console.log(posts);
var found = posts.some(el => el.id  === 2 );
 if(found)
 {
    for(num of posts){
        //console.log (3, num.id);
        if(4 === num.id){ 
          //Your code
            //console.log("error");
        } else {
          //Your code
            //console.log(num);
        }                
    }; 
    posts.push(newObj);
    console.log(posts);
 }
```

Comment: This is awesome. I used this, but without the arrow function, because I'm not good at that yet :P. Thank you very much.

Comment: @PedroSchreiber, other answer showed you how to use `Some()` without `=>`. If my answer works for you then please accept it by green tick

Answer (score 1):

You can use either *Array.prototype.some()* as Andreas suggested or use *Array​.prototype​.find()*.

Array.prototype.some() will just return true or false and will not return the matching object.
If you need the object, use find() as follows:

```
$("#form").submit(function(event) {
event.preventDefault();
var id = Number($("#idPost").val());
var title = $("#titlePost").val();
var date = new Date($("#data").val());
var objectPresent = posts.find(function(post) {
   return post.id === id;
});
if(!objectPresent) {
   var post = new Post(id, title, date);
} else {
  console.log(objectPresent.id,"is already taken up by ", objectPresent.title);
}
```

});

Answer (score 1):

This should work:

```
if (postExists(posts, id)){
    // invlaid post entry
} else {
    // add new post
}

function postExists(posts, id) {
    return posts.some(function(post){
        return post.id == id;
    });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use the JSON object, it will help you to identify easily, that how to identify, is key present in JSON object list or not

```
JSON_Object.hasOwnProperty(ID)
```

---

```
var x = {};
x[1] = "{'title1':'title1'}";
x[2] = "{'title2':'title2'}";
x[3] = "{'title3':'title3'}";

if(x.hasOwnProperty(1)){
 console.log('value present');
}

if(x.hasOwnProperty(5)){
 console.log('value not present');
}
```

This may help you.

This is just a way to resolve your problem.
Use this, thanks me later, cheers :)

Comment: [There's no such thing as a "JSON Object"](http://benalman.com/news/2010/03/theres-no-such-thing-as-a-json/)